# Get ListItem id/position while clicking on RadioButton in that ListItem.

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have 3 `RadioButtons` along with some texts in my `ListItem` using `CursorAdapter`. I need to get the view (ListItem) position when i click any of the `RadioButton` in that `ListItem`. Because , clicking on the `RadioButton` does not mean that i am Clicking on the ListItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bindView or newView:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_id);
radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        Log.d(TAG, cursor.getPosition());
    }
});
```

Also make sure cursor declared as final in method parameters.

Comment: I have 4 list items, all having 3 radio buttons each. and when i apply this solution on any of radio button, it always gives me the position "3" i.e. that position of the last one.

Comment: Thnx alot, its working , i just make the position of cursor **`final`** too.